# How selecting and looking if there is a record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT day='$day','$month' day='$day' year='$year' FROM punchin WHERE pass='$pass' '$month' AND day='$day' AND year='$year' ");


if (mysql_num_rows($sql) === 0) {
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO punchin (count,pass,month,day,year,time,wday) values (null,'$pass','$month','$day','$year','$time','$wday')") or die(mysql_error());
t 

}else
        echo "<a href='loginoption.php'>You can only punch-in once a day!</a>";
```

the problem is .. 
employee should only punchin once a day but this one can punchin anytime.

Comment: `SELECT day='$day'` wrong syntax. There are no `=` in this part of a select.

Comment: Assuming that you're using MySQL, syntax for a SELECT statement is [documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

Comment: But if you're only just learning, learn to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) interface with [prepared statements and bind variables](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), because the MySQL interface will be [officially dropped from PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) before the end of the year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems in your SELECT query, try with this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT day FROM punchin WHERE pass='$pass' AND month = '$month' AND day='$day' AND year='$year'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO punchin (count,pass,month,day,year,time,wday) values (null,'$pass','$month','$day','$year','$time','$wday')") or die(mysql_error());

}else
        echo "<a href='loginoption.php'>You can only punch-in once a day!</a>";
```